# Why does the first part of the code not work correctly while the second part works?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// first part
document.getElementById("creditBal")
        .addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("creditBal");
  var y = document.getElementById("cashBal");
  var z = document.getElementById("totalBal");

  if(y.value == "") {
     z.value = x.value;
  }
  else {
    var tot = parseInt(x.value) + parseInt(y.value);

    z.value = tot + "";
  }
}

// second part
document.getElementById("cashBal")
        .addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("creditBal");
  var y = document.getElementById("cashBal");
  var z = document.getElementById("totalBal");

  if(x.value == "") {
    z.value = y.value;
  }
  else {
    var tot = parseInt(x.value) + parseInt(y.value);

    z.value = tot+"";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code above, both functions are named the same "`myFunction`" which is causing ambiguity. Try naming the functions with different names. Even `myFunction1` and 
`myFunction2` will work just to distinguish them.